# Copy Range from one workbook to another work

Tags: excel, vba

[image]I would like to columns A and I from row 12 down to the first empty row from workbook Test.xslx to
A12 to I12 copy to
workbook LoadNew.xslx The excel showing is the Test.xslx  where I copy from

```
  Dim WB1 As Workbook
    Dim WB2 As Workbook
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim myPath As String
    Dim folderPath As String
    Dim wbSource As Workbook
    Dim sFile As String
    
    folderPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
    myPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    sFile = ActiveWorkbook.name

   Workbooks.Open (folderPath & "\Test.xlsx")

   Set DestSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
   ThisWorkbook.Activate

   Set WB = Workbooks.Open(aFile)
   Set SourceSht = WB.Worksheets("QC Test")
 
   Sheets("QC Test").Select
  
   LastRow = SourceSht.Cells(SourceSht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
 
    SourceSht.Range("A120:I" & LastRow).Copy
    DestSht.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    WB.Close False 'No need to save any changes
```

Comment: What does `Debug.Print LastRow` return?

Comment: It returns a 1 last row

Comment: Then that is the last row in column A on that sheet.

Comment: `End(xlUp)` is the correct way to find the last row... there is some other explanation.

Comment: @GMalc - well, it's getting the last row from `SourceSht` though: `LastRow = SourceSht.Cells(SourceSht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row` Though the `Set WB = Workbooks.Open(aFile)` looks suspicious, especially since the correct workbook it seems was opened previously....hmmm.

Comment: Methinks the code snippet in the question doesn't actually reflect the code OP is using.

Comment: Solved by changing the offset to 12 and column to B